# Code::Block MinGW-w64 запуск программы от имени администратора

Tags: c, mingw

Здравствуйте. Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но ответа я так и не получил. Мне надо что бы мой скомпилированный проект запускался только от имени администратора. Вопрос, как это сделать? Я так понимаю нужно куда-то впихнуть манифест файл, но я так и не нашел куда его пихать, что куда добавлять. Пытался глянуть в интернете - нигде ответа не нашел. Я использую MinGW-w64 + Code::Block IDE. Прошу помочь. Если что, пишу код на Си.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000158/embed-manifest-file-to-require-administrator-execution-level-with-mingw32

Comment: Запускайте Code::Block от имени администратора